# Inability to load objects exported from Blender into three.js?

Tags: javascript, json, 3d, three.js, blender

I've been playing around with Blender for quite a bit longer than I've been coding, and was really excited when I learned that you could load and manipulate a blend in the browser using three.js. I looked up a tutorial, exported a simple icosphere, and plugged in my .json file. Alas, after looking at numerous different pages and examples, I still can't seem to get it to appear in the browser, despite not being able to find any visible errors in my code. I made a codepen project out of it (it was the only way I could find to get the json file online).

```
https://codepen.io/redheadedmandy/project/editor/ZjNEQG#0
```

Here's the snippet of code to call the .json file:

```
function initMesh() {
    function addModelToScene(geometry, materials) {
        var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
        model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        model.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
        model.position.set(50, 0, 0);
        scene.add(model);

        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        loader.load("casvusnion.json", addModelToScene);
    }
}
```

If anyone can spot a problem, or has a suggestion for what the issue might be, I would much appreciate the help!

Comment: So, this time it's r75. Much better than r71 :) Though the latest version is r88.

Comment: It's often a good idea to try importing your model into the [threejs editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) first, to make sure it's exported correctly. In this case it works, but note that it's way off center.

Comment: Was it helpful?

Comment: ... I can't believe I'm still not using the latest version. Sigh. I've also realized, thanks to your reminder to use the console log, that the reason it's failing is because of cross-origin request issues with local files... I'm going to have to find a workaround, but got distracted with another project!

Comment: @AmandaHarvey You're welcome )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function initMesh() {

    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load("casvusnion.json", addModelToScene);

    function addModelToScene(geometry, materials) {

        var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
        model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        model.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
        model.position.set(50, 0, 0);
        scene.add(model);

    }

}
```

And check your browser's console log for warnings and error messages.

Also, your camera

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 10);
camera.position.set(0, 3.5, 5);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
```

and your model

```
model.position.set(50, 0, 0);
```

It looks like that the model's position is way far from camera's view.

And finally, your project is read-only, so it's impossible for the others to change something there.